# Binding files to forms

Tags: django

I'm working on a project in django and I have a form in which I take files as input. In the documentation it says I'm supposed to bind the file to the form. What does it mean to bind the files to a form?

Comment: It means to have an input in the form that is a file input

Comment: You really need to post some code and be explicit about the error you've got. Or have a look for a similar question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814215/binding-files-to-forms-in-django

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form

Comment: I haven't gotten an error, I'm just trying to understand what it means to 'bind' a file to a form.

Answer (score 0):

*This is an excerpt from Django Forms API Documentation*

> In practice, you will usually specify request.FILES as the source of
> file data (just like you use request.POST as the source of form data):

## Bound form with an image field, data from the request

```
f = ContactFormWithMugshot(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Constructing an unbound form is the same as always – omit both form data and file data:

## Unbound form with an image field

```
f = ContactFormWithMugshot()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form